# Universal audio player with controls in multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Audioboo iOS app has a universal audio player with controls (i.e. play/pause button.) view always visible on loaded view controllers when playing content. Also sometimes the view controllers themselves have controls as well (play/pause button and a countdown timer)

My question is what's the best way to know when loading a view that the player is playing its  corresponding content and update this view's control state and timer?

Check these screenshot links 
http://cl.ly/image/2k213Q0L2U2w
http://cl.ly/image/3o0F0a150d1T
//The bottom player view is always visible when navigating between view controllers.

**NOTE :**
  This is my first question ever here, so please let me know if you have any questions or want me to clear something up :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class that manages audio player you should add public property, that would point on currently playing entity. For instance:

```
@interface MyAudioPlayer : AVPlayer
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) Song *currentSong
...
@end
```

and don't forget to assign corresponding song to this property whenever the new song starts playing.

Then you would be able to access this current song from any view controller.

**UPD:**

After some clarification, I post update for future reference.
In order to manage correspondence between player data and UI part for multiple `UIViewControllers` there are 3 main approaches:

1) You might want to use `NSNotification`, sent by player manager class when some event appears (like changing the song, etc.) and intercepted by your view controllers.

2)  You might want to use [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/keyvalueobserving/KeyValueObserving.html) and subscribe your view controllers to changes in player class.

3) You might want to take a look at [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) which is replacement to KVO paradigm.

Comment: I know how to access and control current playing content. my problem is is that in visible view controllers i want to know which content is playing and update timer and control state in that view. My solution so far, or not so complete solution, is to get the content id from the player (which is a singleton) and compare it to the content in views when loaded. I can also update the timer using NSTimer getting the time from the player.

Comment: you can use notifications like `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`, catch them in your player and it would inform via delegation or notifications your view controllers that they need update their content or use KVO for the `currentSong` property.

Comment: For some reason I don't like posting notifications like this but it seems this is the only thing that would work. Thanks!

Comment: As another option, you can take a look at [Reactive Cocoa](http://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa), this might simplify tracking events related to player/song state changes.
If you are satisfied with my answer, could you please accept it and up vote it?
Glad to help you.

Comment: I up voted it. I'm not sure how this thing works here but maybe you should include the actual answer in the answer body itself?

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom tab-bar that plays the song and has a bar to track progress and such. Then when you change views, the 'current song' view will not change and will remain the same. You could also just add a custom view on the top of the screen using the AppDelegate. Hope that helps!

Comment: My problem is not with creating the global control view! check my comment on @Alexander answer

Comment: Ahh, I see. Delegation is the way forward.